# shadow-cljs - socket connect failed, server process dead?

Tags: clojurescript, shadow-cljs

I'm using [shadow-cljs](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs) in a ClojureScript project. When I do

```sh
shadow-cljs watch app
```

the console log the error `shadow-cljs - socket connect failed, server process dead?`.

I restarted my computer but the error still

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does it not continue after showing this error? Make sure you are on a recent version.

This is more like a warning if the server instance wasn't properly shutdown previously. If it doesn't continue normally after printing that message you can wipe the `.shadow-cljs` directory to fix it although it is supposed to fix itself in this case.

Comment: Just ran into this. I had killed my process. Wiping `.shadow-cljs/` and rerunning `watch` removed the warning, and sped up the startup time of subsequent calls to `watch`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have faced a similar problem. The solution below worked for me:

> Deleting all files (only files) except `classpath.edn`. And re-run your app.